# SQL: Why are NULL values filtered out within this where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

In my table, I have a nullable bit column (legacy system...) and another developer recently made a change to a stored procedure to only show values where the bit column was not true (1).  Because this is a nullable column, we noticed that if the column was NULL, the record was not being picked up.  WHY is this?

Both the other developer and I agree that NULL <> 1...  Is this a bug in SQL or was this designed this way?  Seems like a design flaw.

**Current Code:**

```
(VoidedIndicator <> 1)
```

**Proposed Fix:**

```
(VoidedIndicator <> 1 OR VoidedIndicator IS NULL)
```

**Clarification (By Jon Erickson)**

VoidedIndicator is a nullable bit field so it can have the following values: NULL, 0, or 1

When a SQL statement is created with a where clause such as (VoidedIndicator <> 1) we only get records returned that have VoidedIndicator == 0, but we were expecting both VoidedIndicator == 0 and VoidedIndicator IS NULL. Why is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia entry on NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Common_mistakes):

> For example, a WHERE clause or
> conditional statement might compare a
> column's value with a constant. It is
> often incorrectly assumed that a
> missing value would be "less than" or
> "not equal to" a constant if that
> field contains Null, but, in fact,
> such expressions return Unknown. An
> example is below:
>
> ```
> -- Rows where num is NULL will not be returned,
> -- contrary to many users' expectations.
> SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE num <> 1;
> ```

Basically, *any* comparison between NULL and something else, whether it's with = or <> will not be true.

As another reference, the [MSDN T-SQL page on `<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176020(SQL.90).aspx) states:

> Compares two expressions (a comparison
> operator). When you compare nonnull
> expressions, the result is TRUE if the
> left operand is not equal to the right
> operand; otherwise, the result is
> FALSE. If either or both operands are
> NULL, see SET ANSI_NULLS
> (Transact-SQL).

The [SET ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048(SQL.90).aspx) page then states:

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a SELECT
> statement that uses WHERE column_name
> = NULL returns zero rows even if there are null values in column_name. A
> SELECT statement that uses WHERE
> column_name <> NULL returns zero rows
> even if there are nonnull values in
> column_name.
>
> ...
>
> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, all
> comparisons against a null value
> evaluate to UNKNOWN. When SET
> ANSI_NULLS is OFF, comparisons of all
> data against a null value evaluate to
> TRUE if the data value is NULL.

Answer (score 15):

Lots of good answers, but let me give you a really concise version.

To SQL, Null does NOT mean "No value" it means "Unknown Value"

With that in mind, consider the answer to the question you are asking SQL in plain English.

```
Q: Is this unknown value not equal to 1? 
A: I don't know, there is no way to tell without knowing the value.

Hence Null<>1 = Null
```

Comment: appreciate the layman's terms - seeing it not evaluate to a boolean makes sense.. I always forget our pal NULL.  this just stopped our entire accounting integration _*nervous chuckle*_

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug.

NULL is not equal to anything, not even NULL (NULL = NULL returns FALSE).

Typically NULL values aren't indexed either. It's generally a bad idea to rely on a particular value or NULL. Depending on what you're storing in the column, you may be better off putting a dummy or sentinel value in rather than using NULL to indicate some meaning.

Comment: So if NULL is not equal to anything as you say, then how does NULL not get included in this?  Column <> 1...  NULL does not equal 1?  Correct?

Comment: Any comparison involving NULL returns false so yes NULL <> 1 is false. That's what IS NULL or IS NOT NULL is for.

Comment: The best way I find to think about nulls in database terminology, rightly or wrongly, is that a null value is "unknown", therefore cannot compared to another null value, nor compared to a concrete value

Comment: @cletus: It's more accurate to say that NULL<>1 is "unknown" because if it were false, then NOT(NULL<>1) would be true.  Instead, applying NOT to unknown is still unknown.

Answer (score 1):

The other folks are correct that `NULL <> 1` doesn't evaluate as true, therefore it doesn't satisfy the `WHERE` clause.

The proposed fix you describe is the best way of handling it:

```
(VoidedIndicator <> 1 OR VoidedIndicator IS NULL)
```

SQL-99 does have a predicate that helps in this case, called `IS DISTINCT FROM`:

```
(VoidedIndicator IS DISTINCT FROM 1)
```

This predicate would behave exactly the same as your proposed fix.  Unfortunately, Microsoft SQL Server does not support `IS DISTINCT FROM` yet.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'd not come across IS DISTINCT FROM before. So this still hasn't been implemented in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Right.  I cannot find IS DISTINCT FROM in the MS SQL Server 2008 online documentation, whereas I do find the IS NULL predicate and the ISNULL() function.

Comment: PostgreSQL, IBM DB2, and Firebird support IS DISTINCT FROM.  Oracle and Microsoft do not.  MySQL supports an operator "<=>".

Answer (score 0):

You can also: isnull(VoidedIndicator,1) <> 1

Comment: Bad idea for performance unless you have a functional index for this sort of thing.

Comment: @cletus that is considering they have an scenario that actually needs that optimization. I do agree on using a default value where possible/appropriate though.

Answer (score 0):

Because the WHERE clause only selects rows when the condition evaluates to true.

When one of the operands is NULL, the condition usually evaluates to UNKNOWN (approximately equivalent to NULL), and therefore is not true.  It applies to both '`column = 1`' and '`column <> 1`'; if column is NULL, the search condition fails.

It is why you get told to avoid NULL columns whenever possible.

Comment: Do you also avoid the integer value zero, since division by zero causes an error?

Comment: It might depend on the server, but the chances are decent that if you write 'column / 0' and column is null, then the division code looks to see if either operand is null and returns null before generating the 'divide by zero' error.  However, if you know 'column' is null, why are you dividing it?

Comment: And why are you dividing by zero, anyway?   I think it would be unwise to rely on nulls preventing divide by zero errors, but if you divide a null by zero 'accidentally', then you probably don't get the error.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me...  You say to avoid NULL, because NULL has some special logic you have to handle.  But this would be like prohibiting zero, just because you have to handle zero specially in a division operation.  Just suck it up and do the checks!

Comment: Yes; I completely misinterpreted the question.  No, I don't avoid zero; I merely avoid division by zero.  I avoid null when I can, which is most (but not all) of the time.

Answer (score 0):

NULL <> 1 evaluates (theoretically) to "maybe", which means the record will not be returned.