# Microsoft sql stored procedure not executing select statement properly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm pretty new to Microsoft T-sql (Use to Oracle PL/SQL) and I ran into a annoying problem with a very simple procedure.

I created the following procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ele_test] @productId INT
AS
DECLARE @productCode VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @productDescription VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @error VARCHAR(100);

--Fetch product 
IF @productId != NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @productCode = ProductCode
        ,@productDescription = ProductDescription
    FROM d_afterpay.dbo.Product
    WHERE ProductId = @productId
END

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    SET @error = 'Product not found: ' + cast(@productId AS VARCHAR(19))

    RAISERROR (@error,16,1);
END
```

And when I run it this way:

```
exec ele_test 5
```

I get:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ele_test, Line 20
Product not found. Productid : 5
```

Yet when I run just the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM d_afterpay.dbo.Product
        WHERE ProductId = 5
```

I do get a proper result...
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this really the code that's causing the problem? I'd expect you to get a message like `Product not found: 5` from the code you've posted, not `Product not found. ProductId = 5`

Comment: it indeed gives `Product not found: 5`, sloppy copy&paste work ;)

Comment: OK. The problem probably is in the code youu posted. No idea what it is though; I'll keep staring at it!

Comment: @ErikL try the modification in my answer, that should fix your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query syntax is slightly wrong, change the query to read:

```
IF (@productId IS NOT NULL)
```

instead of using `!=`

This meant your `SELECT` statement was never being called hence why the product was always missing.

Comment: Funny. I didn't spot this although I looked at it. SQL comparison operators are horribly misdesigned.

Comment: isn't it odd that there isn't any a error about the `!=` construction? or does it have some (other) meaning in mssql?

Comment: @ErikL the syntax in your query is actually valid but the way comparison operators and NULLS work caused the problem. See Sir Skeet's post for a detailed explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683627/sql-why-are-null-values-filtered-out-within-this-where-clause/